# Accessing Microsoft SQL Server from iPhone app

Tags: iphone, sql-server

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't.

Instead, you should make a web service that securely exposes the data you need.
(Do **not** write an `ExecuteSQL` method!)

If you really want to connect directly to SQL Server from an iPhone, you'll need to write a [TDS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174503.aspx) client; it will involve a lot of work.

By exposing the data through a web service, you add a layer of abstraction between the database and the client app, allowing you to change the database without breaking the app.

Also, exposing SQL Server directly to the internet is *never* a good idea.

Finally, remember that port 1433 might be blocked at a firewall.